# Detect current page zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I need to know in the main layout, if current page is like "module/controller".
So, for instance, if I am on the page like "site.com/module/controller", the layout which is in "www/module/application/view/layout/layout.phtml" has to understand that I am on that page.

Could you tell me please, how to cope with it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution for that is to set the route parameters as layout variables from your `Module.php`.

Assuming you have a route configuration which looks like this :

```
'route'    => '/[:module[/:controller[/:action]]]
```

You can use the following code :

**In your `Module.php` file :**

```
public function onBootstrap($e)
{
    //....
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $eventManager->attach('dispatch', array($this, 'initView' ));
   //....
}

public function initView(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $controller = $e->getTarget();
    $route = $controller->getEvent()->getRouteMatch();

    //set variables into the layout
    $controller->layout()->modulename = $route->getParam('module');
    $controller->layout()->controllername = $route->getParam('controller');
    $controller->layout()->actionname= $route->getParam('action');
}
```

**Note :** If you haven't `module` in the route parameter you can get it as follows :

```
    $controllerClass = get_class($controller);
    $moduleName = substr($controllerClass, 0, strpos($controllerClass, '\\'));

    $controller->layout()->modulename = $moduleName;
```

**In your layout :**

Now you can access the variables in your layout just like this :

```
Current page :<?php echo $this->modulename.'/'.$this->controllername.'/'.$this->actionname; ?>
```

**Example :**

Page : `site.com/application/index/home`

Output :  `Current page : Application/index/home`